# Using HDF5 on Windows 10: Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_DIR)

Tags: cmake, hdf5

I was successfully able to use HDF5 in my C++ project on MacOS and Linux.

Currently I am trying to get it to work on Windows 10, but I get the following CMake output:

```
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_DIR)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /cygdrive/z/hdf5parser/cmake-build-debug
```

I installed the Pre-built Binary Distribution of HDF5 on Windows and set the environment variable `HDF5_DIR` to `C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.5/cmake`.

According to the official documentation I use the following CMake configuration for my project:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.10)
project (HDF5MyApp C CXX)

set (LIB_TYPE STATIC) # or SHARED
string(TOLOWER ${LIB_TYPE} SEARCH_TYPE)

find_package (HDF5 NAMES hdf5 COMPONENTS C ${SEARCH_TYPE})
set_directory_properties(PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES "${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIR}")
set (LINK_LIBS ${LINK_LIBS} ${HDF5_C_${LIB_TYPE}_LIBRARY})

set (example HdfHandler)

add_executable(...) # I skipped this part

target_link_libraries(hdf5parser PRIVATE ${LINK_LIBS})
```

Had somebody similar problems or can give me a hint to use HDF5 on Windows?

Comment: Do you have `HDF5_DIR` set to your top-level HDF5 directory, which contains the include and lib folders?

Comment: @squareskittles No. As I mentioned in my question I set the path to `C:/Program Files/HDF_Group/HDF5/1.10.5/cmake`. This is the path from the documentation of HDF5.

Comment: Can you verify that the `hdf5-config.cmake` is in that `1.10.5/cmake` folder? That is what CMake uses to set your other HDF5 CMake variables.

Comment: @squareskittles `1.10.5/cmake` does not contain the cmake file directly, but `1.10.5\cmake\hdf5` does. I also tried changing `HDF5_DIR` to this path, but it did not work either.

Comment: I just tested this on my Windows 10 system, and it appears to work. It may help to clear your CMake cache, delete the CMake 'build' folder, and do a fresh CMake run. Also, remember to close and reopen any relevant applications/console windows after updating the system environment variables.

Comment: Also, there appears to be several Pre-built Binary Distributions on the HDFGroup site. Make sure the one you installed matches the version of Visual Studio (14 or 15) you have installed.